# I beat up that annoying reporter. Again. Is that going to be a problem?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Those who have played *Mass Effect* and *Mass Effect 2* will remember Khalisah al-Jilani. The first time I met her, I let her conduct a leading, malicious interview. She smeared my good name, and made a mockery of me on the extranet

So the second time I ran into her, when she tried to corner me and ask more leading questions, I took a swing at her. She deserved it.

Well, having returned to the Citadel in the wake of the Reaper invasion, who would be waiting for me but my old friend Khalisah, who is as arrogant and manipulative as ever. I can't stand her, so I beat the crap out of her. Again.

Is this hostility to reporters *ever* going to catch up to me? Or should I just enjoy the throwaway renegade points?

Comment: After punching 2 reporters in the first two games, My Shepard remarked, in passing, "I don't have a good track record with reporters".

Comment: Correction: You punched one reporter. *Twice.*

Comment: Well, I guess I punched one and threatened another at gunpoint.

Comment: I cannot lie that approximatly a third of my enjoyment from participating in this site stems from the titles that occasionally come up on the newest questions page.

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway, I just love beating her too much.

Comment: Can I not punch her if Diana is the reporter I see in game?

Comment: @Ben it's not an either or - both reporters are on the citadel in different spots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get that reporter as a War Asset if you do the Paragon route. I believe it is not much, but every little bit helps, right?

[image]

Comment: Allow me to add a picture as corroborating evidence. It might be more if you don't punch her in the first two games.

Comment: Nope, did not punch her in the first two games and it still is 5. So I guess that is her fixed value.